# Ability to see whether or not an unregistered user has a valid session

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, unregistered-users

As a moderator, it can be beneficial for me to know whether or not an unregistered account is "still alive" or has been thoroughly abandoned.

An unregistered user has only a cookie based session, without actual login credentials. So if all of the sessions server-side are no longer valid (which is generally caused by said user not coming back for a long enough period), the account is effectively abandoned, this means that

- User will never reply to comments
- User will never add details to their question
- User will never revise his answer

It can also means content can be edited/closed/deleted more aggressively, because the user in question cannot do it himself (even if they were here and wanted to).

In light of that, can we have a moderator ability to see whether or not a user still has valid sessions and have a chance of logging in to their unregistered account? I know it's not foolproof (as user may have cleared cookies on their side to cause the same effect), but it's "close enough" and will help with 99% of the cases.

Comment: In most cases where the user _doesn't_ have a valid session, what action would you take?

Comment: @TimPost I'd usually check for that in response to a flag or a low quality post. If the post is unsalvageable (which more often than not, it is), I can safely delete without attempting to offer advice, or wait for OP to return and reply to me or try to edit their question.

Answer (score 3):

**Check if it has been six months**

If it's been more than half a year, the cookie has expired as it is valid for six months (cf. [How long does an unregistered user's cookie remain valid?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281134/how-long-does-an-unregistered-users-cookie-remain-valid)), so that's the breaking point for a session. So until we get a nicer way to see if there's still a session this might be your workaround.