# How long does an unregistered user's cookie remain valid?

Tags: support, login, unregistered-users, cookies

I was looking at profile of a user who is currently unregistered but has been using Stack Exchange communities since 27th June 2016.

I was wondering how does Stack Exchange keep track of unregistered accounts but [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68524/what-does-it-mean-when-someones-an-unregistered-user) answers that they do it with a long living cookie.

Now I am wondering, how long does that cookie remain valid? Is there a certain time period after which an unregistered user's login cookie becomes invalid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only cookie that is used for authentication is [acct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263363/158100)

When I have the site create me an unregistered account the server sends me this response:

> acct=t=MpkjO9....&s=N4zv...;
>     domain=.stackoverflow
>   .com;
>     expires=Wed, 11-Jan-2017 08:38:29 GMT;
>     path=/;
>     HttpOnly

So I can close this browser window now and if I come back to that same browser within 6 months I should be able to gain access again to that same unregistered account.
If I keep returning, the cookie expiration will slide.

Comment: Guess you were right after all. Check my comments on my deleted post.

Comment: OK, so I trashed my unregistered account for nothing ... boohoobooohooo .. you owe me a coffee ... ;)

Comment: Still wonder what I did wrong with my cookie for SO user 6573618

Comment: You are welcome to come and get a cup of coffee. Any time @rene